# Changing the variable value through looping in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I have the following Ansible playbook: *remove.yaml* that have two variable and it loops through a set of items.

```yaml
- name: calling helm commands tasks
  include_tasks: helm_commands.yaml
  vars:
    name_spce: "sdn"
    extra_parameter: "--no-hooks"

  loop: ['dre','hju','cny','wer','guy']
```

The included tasks file *helm_commands.yaml* is:

```yaml
---

- name: check if {{item}} exist
  shell:
    cmd: /usr/local/bin/helm3 get manifest {{item}} --namespace {{name_spce}}
  register: get_release
  failed_when: get_release.rc ==2

- name: helm delete {{item}}
  shell:
    cmd: /usr/local/bin/helm3 delete {{item}} {{extra_parameter}} --namespace {{name_spce}}
  when: get_release.rc ==0
```

The problem is I want the variable `extra_parameter` take the value `--no-hooks` only when it loop through the first item `'dre'` otherwise take empty value `''`

```
extra_parameter: "--no-hooks" when loop with 'dre'

                 ""           when loop with other items
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [extended loop functionalities](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables) for that:

```yaml
- name: calling helm commands tasks
  include_tasks: helm_commands.yaml
  vars:
    name_spce: "sdn"
    extra_parameter: "{{ '--no-hooks' if ansible_loop.first }}"
  loop: ['dre','hju','cny','wer','guy']
  loop_control:
    extended: yes
```

If you want to add the flag `--no-hooks` regardless of the position of `dre` in the list, then it is as simple as:

```yaml
- name: calling helm commands tasks
  include_tasks: helm_commands.yaml
  vars:
    name_spce: "sdn"
    extra_parameter: "{{ '--no-hooks' if item == 'dre' }}"
  loop: ['dre','hju','cny','wer','guy']
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is almost the solution to my problem. just I want instead of making the condition true when looping through the first item . making it true when find the value 'dre'  as long as not necessary to be always the first item .
I try to modify the condition to be : 
extra_parameter: "{{ '--no-hooks' if ansible_loop.index=='dre' }}
but seems it is not work in this way. if you could help more with this .I am still new to ansible.

Comment: See updated answer